# Delete rectangle after mouse release in PyQt label with QPainter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a rectangular color picker tool in PyQt. I'm stuck on the first step of showing the rectangle on top of an image or more precisely NOT showing the rectangle anymore once the mouse is released after dragging.

My first attempt at implementing it myself I couldn't deleted any previously drawn rectangles and was just left with an image covered with rectangles.

Then I found this code implementing pretty much exactly what I am looking for:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/485354263/

To show the relevant part:

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    self.flag = True
    self.x0 = event.x()
    self.y0 = event.y()
    
def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
    self.flag = False
    
def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
    if self.flag:
        self.x1 = event.x()
        self.y1 = event.y()
        self.update()

def paintEvent(self, event):
    super().paintEvent(event)
    rect = QRect(self.x0, self.y0, abs(self.x1-self.x0), abs(self.y1-self.y0))
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red,2,Qt.SolidLine))
    painter.drawRect(rect)
```

This in combination with an image pixmap for the label does most of what I want.
However, unfortunately I don't understand the code well enough to get where exactly previously drawn rectangles from the `paintEvent` method get deleted, which is what I also want to accomplish in the `mouseReleaseEvent`. This code keeps showing the drawn rectangle and I want it gone after releasing the mouse.

I thought maybe the deleting of previously drawn rectangles happens during the `update`, but just adding `self.update()` to the `mouseReleaseEvent` doesn't do the trick.

So, where exactly are the drawn rectangles deleted and how do I put this inside the release event?

Comment: Ok, I just found a workaround where I set all x0,x1,y0,y1 = 0 and then call update in the mouse release event, but that feels a bit dirty...

Answer (score 0):

Draw rect only when `self.flag` is True. Request repaint after release with `self.update()`.

```py
def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
    self.flag = False
    self.update()

def paintEvent(self, event):
    super().paintEvent(event)
    if not self.flag:
        return
    rect = QRect(
        self.x0, self.y0, abs(self.x1 - self.x0), abs(self.y1 - self.y0))
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2, Qt.SolidLine))
    painter.drawRect(rect)
```